# How to set parent id of child element?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing a survey creator application.

**Survey.java**

```
@Table(name = "SURVEYS")
@Entity
public class Survey implements Serializable{
.
.
.
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "genSurvey")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "genSurvey", sequenceName = "SEQ_SURVEY", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "surveyId")
    private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<Question>();
.
.
.
}
```

**Question.java**

```
@Table(name = "QUESTIONS")
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable{
.
.
.
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "genSurveyQuestions")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "genSurveyQuestions", sequenceName = "SEQ_SURVEY_QUESTIONS", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SURVEY_ID")
    private Survey surveyId;
.
.
.
}
```

while adding a new question to a survey I use following code:

**Test.java**

```
survey.getQuestion().add(question1);
survey.getQuestion().add(question2);

currentSession.saveOrUpdate(survey);
```

After running this code I expect it should persist survey and questions. But I get the following errors:

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400:
>   cannot insert NULL into ("QUESTIONS"."SURVEY_ID")
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("QUESTIONS"."SURVEY_ID")

Somehow it sets questions' surveyIds to null. What's wrong with my OneToMany association, I couldn't figure out. Any help appriciated.

***Note:*** I used the following link as a reference:
http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-many-to-one-association/

Comment: You assoc is lazy. That was wrong with it, or may be it's not always wrong but a minimal example is required to reproduce error.

Comment: Thank you for quick comment @RomanC. How should I change it?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to call `question.setSurvey(survey)` on all the questions before calling `saveOrUpdate(survey)` if it's not the case.

Usually we define a method like this on `Survey` class:

```
public void addQuestion(Question q) {
    q.setSurvey(this);
    questions.add(q);
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand. Is this situation specific to saveOrUpdate? As in this blog post: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/, "The code session.save(stockDailyRecords); is no longer required" when save is used

Comment: The problem is not that you have to call `save` on both the survey and the questions. A single save will save both with cascade. The problem is that cascading doesn't handle setting the id of the survey in the questions objects, you have to do this manually.

Comment: Additionaly I tried your suggestion, but it still gives me same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fetch type EAGER on the collection to get all depenencies from session before `saveOrUpdate` is called.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "surveyId")
```

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't work @RomanC. I'm still getting the same errors.